# Построение запроса для фильтра товаров

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Имею понятие как сделать фильтр по одному параметру, например производителю. Но как правильно составить запрос, чтобы учитывались все выбранные параметры? К примеру, выбрали производителя, цену, ОЗУ и фильтруем. Не могу понять как именно объединить все условия в один запрос

Comment: Where and and and and

Comment: Проверять какие параметры выбраны и конкатенировать новые условия к общему запросу?

Comment: Как-то так, да.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пытаться

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM "Имя твоей таблицы" WHERE "производитель" = "значение" AND "цена" = "значение" AND "ОЗУ" = "значение"